# Is there a way to get a player's respawn coordinates with a PlayerEntity object (Fabricmc)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I made a use override on the Block class

```
public TypedActionResult<ItemStack> use(World world, PlayerEntity playerEntity, Hand hand) {
   // code in here
}
```

is there a way to use the playerEntity variable to get the player's respawn coorindates?

Comment: there isn't respawn event ? or check in the world the spawn coords ?

Comment: there are 2 i found ```requestRespawn()``` but I cant get that to do anything, and ```findRespawnposition()``` but that requires a serverWorld Object which I dont think I can get from a World Object

Comment: In Spigot, you should can for CraftWorld then use `getHandle()`. So I suggest to check if by casting it works (idk I don't make fabricmc code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late, but what you need, to get the spawn point of a player, is either a `ServerWorld` object or a `ServerPlayerEntity` object. Because `ServerPlayerEntity` and `ServerWorld` are subclasses of PlayerEntity and World, you can just perform a runtime type-check using `instanceof` and then cast the objects to their subclass.

`ServerPlayerEntity` has a getter called `getSpawnPointPosition` (which returns the spawn position of the player, e.g. the bed position)

`ServerWorld` has a method called `getSpawnPos` (which returns the worlds spawn point)

The `findRespawnPosition` method is used to get a position near the given point, that is not obstructed. So you'd for example provide the players bed spawn to `findRespawnPosition` and the method returns a position, that's not inside a block and tall enough for the player to stand. You would use that method if you want to teleport a player to their respawn point.